# Useful xcode shortcuts

Tags: xcode

I'm novice with Xcode. Could you please hint me which Xcode shortcuts to show

- documentation of an object;
- which methods are available for the object.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press on an element once the inline documentation will be displayed in a small box. If you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> twice, the documentation will be opened in a new window. The screenshot shows the sincle tap:

[image]

For other shortcuts you can access and change the xCode shortcuts in Preferences -> Key Bindings

[image]

For me the tool you can find on [this website](http://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/) is the best for all shortcuts on your mac. After installing, you always can display all shortcuts of a program. You press <kbd>CMD</kbd> and you get the shortcuts of the program which is acutaly selected:

[image]

Comment: Danke! Merci! Di Di Madloba!